# Symfony2 and Vim recommendations

Tags: php, vim, symfony, twig

I already work with Symfony2 and of course with vim but in different projects. I would like to know which plugins, tips, recommendations do you use in Vim for working with Symfony2?

This also goes to Twig template, themes, debugging, etc.

Comment: Not only for Symfony but for PHP in general, great vim configuration: https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really think Symfony2 projects are that much different from any other PHP projects (vim-wise at least). The only extra plugin I use is [Jinja highlighting one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1856) as Jinja syntax is almost identical to Twig. I'm developing also in Django, so I sticked with that one, but there's also [Twig highlighting plugin](https://github.com/beyondwords/vim-twig) if you want something that's going to be up to date with Twig.

If you want to see my vim files, they are on [github](https://github.com/ondrowan/vimfiles), but there's nothing really Symfony2 specific apart from what I described above.

Comment: Anything for debugging? Thanks for your answer, was helpful for Twig.

Comment: No, no debugging plugins for now. I use test-driven development if applicable, that saves a lot of time debugging wise.

Comment: Ohh, that's bad. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Fixed, sorry for that.

Comment: Symfony2 projects are different from other PHP projects.  At least, they have a unique organization of the code parts that could be exploited by a Vim plugin.  There is a Symfony1 plugin that helps you jump from view to controller and back, for example.

Answer (score 1):

We use https://github.com/docteurklein/vim-symfony plugin. Helps a lot, and we use htmljinja file type for template highlighting.